# Elastic Search - How to query for one to many table joins with AND

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, nested

I am new to elastic search. May I know if the following query could be achieved by Elastic search? If so, what should the query string look like?

Input: a sql like sentence. The Sentence is:  "(A and B) and (C and D)"

A, B, C, D are field comparison. E.g, A ->   field "Staff Name" has Value equal to "John".

E.g, There are 2 tables. Employee Table and Task Table.

**Employee Table**

StaffName: John

StaffName: Mary

**Task Table**

TaskName: JohnTaskA,  StaffName: John

TaskName: JohnTaskB,  StaffName: John

TaskName: MaryTaskA,  StaffName: Mary

So in traditional DB,  John could link up to JohnTaskA and JohnTaskB as a 1 to many relationship.

My expected behaviour for the query behaviour (A and B) and (C and D)  is as below:

After (A and B) query, assume only return one record.  John -> JohnTaskA

and after (C and D) query, assume only return one record. John -> JohnTaskB

Then, the following query
(A and B) and (C and D) 
should return no value since "John -> JohnTaskA" not match with "John -> JohnTaskB" actually.

In opposite, if (C and D) query, only return one record out as John -> JohnTaskB

Then the following query
(A and B) and (C and D) 
could return the record John back.

But I cannot acheive this expect behaviour by elastic search query. In my first attempt I use nestedQuery to handle the Task Table's query, and could successfully achieve the multiple column checking in the nested table.

E.g if A ->  Task.TaskName = JohnTaskA,    B -> Task.StaffName = John, then A and B could return a record.

But if A -> Task.TaskName = JohnTaskA,    B -> Task.StaffName = Mary, then A and B could not return any record.

But I found if in this case

(A and B) and (C and D)

I could not use the middle "and" to link up two nested query result together. It doesn't return the expect behaviour.

In case the SQL sentence cannot be changed, may I know how could elastic search achieve this query? or I need to use other ways like parent-child relationships?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

For (A AND B) AND (C AND D),

(A AND B) return the child record with id=c1.

(C AND D) return the child record with id=c2.

Even they share the same parent record (say parent record id =p1), since c1 != c2, (A AND B) AND (C AND D) returns no record if query by SQL, But using elastic search, it still return the record p1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface this by saying that elasticsearch is not an RDMS and you shouldn't use it as such. In elasticsearch, it's much better (query performance, replication performance, write performance, etc_) to denormalize your data.

With that said, since you have specific querying needs, you should pre-define your index mapping such that you could maintain the relationship between objects. To this end, you could use [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) property types or (as a last resort) [join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) property types within mappings.

An example mapping that you might want to consider is within an index you that might call `staff_tasks`:

```
PUT staff_tasks
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "task": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
          },
          "staff": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would then be able to query this using the REST APIs. For example, using the match query:

```
GET staff_tasks/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "staff.name": "john"
    }
  }
}
```

This query would return all `staff_tasks` whom as has a name of "john" (case insensitive) with the "related" task information within the same response.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use sql, you could use the [sql restful endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest-overview.html), as so:

```
POST _sql
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM staff_tasks WHERE task.staff.name = 'john'"
}
```

Comment: I could used the nestedQuery to search the child record, but I cannot link up the 2 child records. Is there a good way to handle this?    For my case,  (A AND B) AND (C AND D).     (A AND B) return the child record with id=c1.  (C AND D) return the child record with id = c2. Even they share the same parent record (say parent record id =p1),   since c1 != c2, (A AND B) AND (C AND D) returns no record if query by SQL, But using elastic search, it still return the record p1.